# Changing values within a list out of a data file

Tags: python, list, readfile

I want to read a data file with various numerical entrys and want the absolute values of each entry. The data file has a header, which I'd like to skip.
My code so far is:

```
import numpy as np

file = 'cps_1.dat'
content = np.genfromtxt(file,skiprows=6)

for i in content:
    if content[i] < 0:
        content[i] = content[i]*-1


out = open('workfile.dat', 'w')
for item in content:
    out.write("%s\n" % item)
```

My output confuses me, because some values are corectly modified, but some others are not. Any ideas?
Here are the first 30 lines of my input and output file to showcase the problem:

Input

```
-14.369884
571.852281
571.852281
571.852281
571.852281
571.852281
571.852281
-3.987742
-344.416453
-568.752721
-568.752721
-568.752721
-568.752721
-568.752721
-568.752721
-568.752721
-568.752721
-568.752721
-568.752721
-568.752721
-347.725839
-89.10072
14.945966
-3.087168
-90.995559
-199.680855
-282.292899
-311.299381
-277.720216
-189.0793
```

Output

```
14.369884
571.852281
571.852281
571.852281
571.852281
571.852281
571.852281
3.987742
344.416453
568.752721
568.752721
568.752721
568.752721
568.752721
568.752721
568.752721
568.752721
568.752721
568.752721
568.752721
347.725839
89.10072
14.945966
3.087168
90.995559
199.680855
282.292899
-311.299381
-277.720216
189.0793
```

Comment: It's a first: I'd have never thought to multiply a number by `-1` to get its absolute value (at the very least, use `n = -n`... multiplication is heavier than negation). Then please be aware that `i` is not an index, but an element of the array rather. Furthermore: avoid indexing if possible. Python has plenty of resources to iterate on sequences and `numpy` can surely act on the whole lot in one go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `for i in content` loops over the values (not the indices!) in `content`, but then you try to use these values as indices. Usually that should throw an `IndexError` for your values and I am surprised that you don't mention one.

Anyway, if you just want to get the absolute values, do this:

```
content = np.abs(content)
```

then write `content` back to your file.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
for i in content:
```

should be

```
for i in range(len(content)):
```

As you want to iterate the indices of content, not the numbers in the list directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in abs(x) function to get the absolute value of a number.

Here's a better way to handle the list (and skipping the first 6 lines).  This uses the list opject function "pop", to pull each number from the back of the line, building a new list.

```
file = '/tmp/input.dat'

with open(file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = content[6:]

new_list = []

while len(content) > 0:
    new_list.insert(0, abs(float(content.pop())))

out = open('/tmp/workfile.dat', 'w')
for item in new_list:
    out.write("%s\n" % item)
```